# Is there a way to execute SQL query in BigQuery depending on the day of week?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's assume I have got this query in a CTE, a really simple one as an example:

```
with cte as (
Select account_create_date, count(user_name) new_accounts_count
from `users_account`
where users_status = 2
group by 1
)
```

How can I run the above query only on Tuesdays, for example? If today is not Tuesday, it should not run the query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is `to schedule queries`.

The operation on BigQuery console is not complicated, the core part is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries.

However, to achieve the expected effect, we need to look at other stuffs, like permissions (IAM).

So, it would be great that we follow this official document step by step (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).

It would take some iterations of experiments. You will make it done.